# Batch Scripting for Spread sheet compare tool to compare two excel file and give the output excel file

Tags: excel, batch-file, compare, spreadsheet, batch-processing

I need a help on writing the .bat file to

1. Open the Spredsheetcompare.exe tool.
2. Load File1.xlsx and File2.xlsx
3. Compare.
4. Give the output.xlsx file as a result of comparison file.xlsx and file2.xlsx

I tried the following code.

```
@echo off

set EXCEL="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE"
set COMPARETOOL="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Client\\AppVLP.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\Office16\\DCF\\SPREADSHEETCOMPARE.EXE"
set File1="C:/Batch Programming/Bat2/File1.xlsx"
set File2="C:/Batch Programming/Bat2/File2.xlsx"
set OUTPUT_FILE="C:/Batch Programming/Bat2/output.x`your text`lsx"

%COMPARETOOL% %EXCEL% /x /r  %File1% %File2% %OUTPUT_FILE%
pause
```

Its not working and not able to load two Excel file in the compare spreadsheet tool.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the comment section did not have the layout or functionality for this advice, so here it is in the answer area.

I would start by simply using the correct and recommended syntax. That means recommended doublequoting, and using the correct Windows path separators:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "FILE1=C:\Batch Programming\Bat2\File1.xlsx"
Set "FILE2=C:\Batch Programming\Bat2\File2.xlsx"
Set "OUTPUT_FILE=C:\Batch Programming\Bat2\output.xlsx"

Set "EXCEL=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
Set "AVU=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\root\client\AppVLP.exe"
Set "COMPARETOOL=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\DCF\SPREADSHEETCOMPARE.EXE"

"%AVU%" "%COMPARETOOL%" "%EXCEL%" /x /r "%FILE1%" "%FILE2%" "%OUTPUT_FILE%"

Pause
```

You'll note that I've separated the application virtualization utility from the spreadsheet compare tool, simply because it makes more sense.

Anyhow, please give it a try, and post feedback as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, for you answer, I tried this,  but still it is not working, and I could not able to see the out file (the result of comparison) its not getting generated.
Can you please help, why this file is not getting generated.

Comment: The idea of this was that you copied it, ran it, and updated your question with the code, results, output, and debugging information. Then I could delete this comment from the answer area. If you begin by changing `Off` to `On` on the first line, you can paste the content of the Command Prompt window as part of that.